# Boundary value problem of 2nd order ODE

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the following second order differential equation with boundary conditions.
\begin{equation}
    \begin{cases}
     -u''(t) = 1+u(t),\ t\in(-1,1)\\
        u(t)>0\ for \ t \in (-1,1)\\
        u(-1)=u(1)=0.
 \end{cases}
\end{equation}
Can we obtain that u(-t)=u(t) for $t\in(-1,1)$?
I alredy known that
\begin{equation}
     \tilde{u}(t)=u(-t)\ is\ a\ solution\ if\ u\ is\ a\ solution,\\
        u'\ is\ strictly\ decreasing, \\
        u'(-1^+)=\lim_{\delta\rightarrow 0^+} \frac{u(-1+\delta)-u(-1)}{\delta}>0,\ and\\
        u'(1^-)=\lim_{\delta\rightarrow 0^+} \frac{u(1)-u(1-\delta)}{\delta}<0.
\end{equation}

If the equation is
$$-u''(t) = 1+u(t)+u(t)^2-u(t)^3,\ t\in(-1,1)$$
will u(-t)=u(t) for $t\in(-1,1)$ hold?

Comment: Are you sure about the question? $u(-t)=u(-t)$ for all $t\in ]-1,1[$. Maybe is it a typo?

Comment: Sorry, It should be "u(-t)=u(t)". I edited it.

Comment: Why don't you solve the problem? Multiply through by $u'$ and integrate to get $$-u'^{2} = u^{2} + 2u + C$$ then separate and integrate.

Comment: I initially want to ask a problem with nonliear ode, but I just notice that I deleted the nonlinear term.

Comment: For the nonlinear ODE you can still multiply through by $u'$ and integrate to get $$-u'^{2} = 2 u + u^{2} + \frac{2}{3} u^{3} - \frac{1}{2} u^{4}$$ which is again separable but probably much harder to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equation $-u''(t) = 1+u(t)$ has the general solution

$$u(t) = c_2 \cos t+c_2 \sin t-1.$$

The boundary conditions give

$$c_2=0, \quad c_1= \frac{1}{\cos 1}.$$

Now it is easy to see that $u(t) >0$ for all $t \in (-1,1)$.

Consequence: the boundary value problem has the unique solution

$$u(t)= \frac{1}{\cos 1} \cos t-1.$$

This gives

$$u(-t)=u(t).$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer.